# How do I make a div that "floats" above all the other content in HTML with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a div, that pops up when the user hovers on a specific object with JS. I know all that. But my problem is, that the div is within the text and makes everything ugly when it pops up. I want it to float above the text. Is that possible with CSS? If not, is it possible with a plugin or a scripting language?

Comment: I think you could use the position: absolute; or you could check out Bootstrap and try out their modal plugin http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Position Absolute works! Thanks!

Comment: @Siyah Yeah, I've learned a lot over that time period about asking questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please refer the example below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="floating">Floating Div</div>
    <div>
        <p>Para Text Goes Here</p>
        <p>More Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is your CSS:

```
.container {
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
.floating {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

**Things to do:**

The use of **POSITION:RELATIVE** on container and **POSITION:ABSOLUTE** on floating div

please have a look at the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/tH84L/

Hope it works for you!

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps....

```
<body>

<div id="aFloat">float</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    position: relative
}
#aFloat {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;

width: 200px;
height: 100px;

background-color: grey;
color: white;
}
```